# How can I change the date format in Eclipse editor templates?

Tags: eclipse

Is there *any* way, other than rebuilding the JDT, to configure the date format of `{$date}` variables in Eclipse editor templates? Or even creating a new variable to match the format I want?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Neon v4.6 RC2 - JDT.  The date variable and/or SimpleDateFormat in templates has been updated.  I use the following to include date and time:
${d:date('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}

See the answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131712/how-to-set-the-eclipse-date-variable-format

Comment: Thanks, @OsmundFrancis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, no, there is no way (using only the current template mechanism)

Only some kind of [macro mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623732/6309) would allow to record some kind of custom date generation (by opening a Scrapbook, evaluating a `System.out.println` of a date in the format you want, copy the result and paste it within your code(!)

[image: scrapbook]