# Unexpected Java code comments generated by Eclipse Code Templates?

Tags: java, eclipse, comments, code-templates

As we know,Eclipse can help us generate code comments for types and methods,e.g,we can go
`Preferences > Java > Code Style > Code Templates > Comments` to configure a template for Java types.
Here is my template for Types:

```
/**
 * @className:${package_name}.${file_name}
 * @description:${todo}
 * @author <a href="mailto:author@website.com">Author</a>
 * @date ${date} ${time}
 */
```

Well when I press
<kbd>/</kbd>  <kbd>*</kbd>   <kbd>*</kbd>  and  <kbd>Enter</kbd>  before a class type,the Eclipse will generate comments below:

```
/**
 * 
 * @className:com.abc.demo.Demo.java
 * @description:TODO
 * @author <a href="mailto:author@website.com">Author</a>
 * @date May 26, 2013 8:56:12 AM
 */
```

In fact,there are two things which are **not** what I expected.

1. There is a blank line before `@className`,so everytime I have to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to delete it;
2. The date format is not what I expected(I wish it could be `2013-05-26` but it is `May 26, 2013`),and what’s even weirder is,the time is not correct(or Not my timezone's current time?)

So can it really generated code templates as I will below:

```
/**
* @className:com.abc.demo.Demo.java
* @description:TODO
* @author <a href="mailto:author@website.com">Author</a>
* @date 2013-05-26 09:30 PM
*/
```

btw,I am working on Windows 7 with Eclipse Helios.

Answer (score 1):

About the date formatting, have a look at this SO entry : [How to set the Eclipse date variable format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131712/how-to-set-the-eclipse-date-variable-format)

In short, setting "-Duser.language" and "-Duser.region" may help.