# Eclipse generated Javadoc ${date} format

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to change the way ${date} value is set by Eclipse when writting Javadoc ? The default one does not suit me.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This was a bug of Eclipse, solved in [Bug 75981](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=75981) .
Its solution is able with recent Eclipse Neon.

More information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35231005/1197323

As said in this post, you can edit the template date in "Preferences->Java->Code Style->Code Templates":

[image]

And it will change the date format:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

if you want to change the format of your eclipse date, just add following two lines to the `eclipse.ini` file:

`-Duser.language="language code"` 
    `-Duser.region="language code"`

like

`-Duser.language=hi`
   `-Duser.region=Hi`

I think it will help.