# How can I record and replay macros in Eclipse 3.5?

Tags: eclipse, macros, recording, replay

Which tool would you recommend for macro recording and replaying ? Is there a language as well ? I frequently switch between Eclipse and Emacs(actually Xemacs) for editing tasks.

It would be nice if I didn't have to do as frequently. That would happen if a macro language/recorder were available in eclipse. It's available in Netbeans, so how come that is not a priority for eclipse ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Macro Recorder for Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103202/is-there-a-macro-recorder-for-eclipse)

Answer (score 5):

There is no current macro language on Eclipse:

- [Practical Macro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalmacro/files/) <del>is not compatible with current 3.5 or 3.6 Eclipse)</del> (update 2014: it has been updated since 2010).
- The official proposal [Eclipse Monkey](http://www.eclipse.org/proposals/eclipse-monkey/) has been withdrawn.
- And the [**bug 8519**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8519) records the absence of keystroke macro since 2002! (130 votes too), even though there have been [some experiment](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=234710).

So your best bet is right now:

- [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) on Windows
- [AutoKey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/) on unix

, which are completely separated from Eclipse, but can at least record and send key events to any application.

Comment: thank you.

I use Autohotkey but only for big tasks with various apps. For small text tasks, I tend to use emacs(Xemacs). I just didn't want to switch between eclipse and emacs as frequently as I did . That would be possible if eclipse' editor gets better with macro, etc.

Comment: Practical Macro -> 404 - File or directory not found.

Comment: @Ruwantha I have restored the link to Practical Macro.